# How to pass hidden variable to a form in django so it could be validated?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a registration form that goes through all the usual stuff, but with one bot prevention thing. I made a model SecurityQuestion, that consists of two charfields, Question and Answer. During registration one of them is randomly picked and is supposed to pass an answer to the form so it can be validated there. However, for the reason I'm yet to figure out, it doesn't seem to be passing the answer to the form

So let's start with the code

**profile/forms.py**

```
# FORM: Register an account
class UserRegistrationFirstForm(forms.ModelForm):

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email_confirm = forms.EmailField()

    answer = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    hidden_answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'email_confirm',
            'password',
            'password_confirm',
            'answer',
        ]

    def clean_answer(self):

        formated_user_answer = self.cleaned_data.get("answer").lower()
        formated_hidden_answer = self.cleaned_data.get("hidden_answer").lower()

        if formated_hidden_answer != formated_user_answer:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorect answer to security question!")

        return answer
```

As you can see, there are two fields, `answer` and `hidden_answer`. `answer` is where users types in their answers, and `hidden_answer` is supposed to be populated when initializing form and passing init.

**profiles/views.py**

```
# VIEW: Register an account
def custom_register(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(reverse('profile', host='profiles'))

    # Grab a random registration security Q&A
    qa_count = SecurityQuestion.objects.count() - 1
    sec_qa = SecurityQuestion.objects.all()[randint(0, qa_count)]


    # Form for users to register an account
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None, initial={"hidden_answer": sec_qa.answer,})

    # Validate the registration form
    if form.is_valid():

        # Create new account
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        # Set the default avatar
        user.profile.avatar = get_default_avatar()
        user.profile.save()

        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Welcome " + user.username + ", you have successfully registered an account!")
        return redirect(reverse('pages:frontpage', host='www'))

    # Context dict to return for template
    context = {
        "title": "Registration",
        "form": form,
        "question": sec_qa.question,
    }
    return render(request, 'profiles/register.html', context)
```

Alright, so in registration view, I randomly pick one of the security questions and then pass it to the form with `initial={"hidden_answer": sec_qa.answer,}`. However it doesn't seem the be going through, as I'm getting following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
Exception Location: path/to/profiles/forms.py in clean_answer, line 103
formated_hidden_answer = self.cleaned_data.get("hidden_answer").lower()
```

OK, so NoneType would mean there's nothing to reference to. I've tried couple different ways to fix this. I tried putting hidden_answer in form's meta field list. I also tried `{{ form.hidden_answer.as_hidden }}` in the template (which is complete opposite of what I'm trying to achieve here, as the answer is still displayed in value of that hidden input in the page source). Any idea what am I doing wrong with this?

EDIT: If there's an alternative or a simple solution to what I'm trying to do, could you please reference any documentation about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a hidden input can't prevent a user from knowing the hidden_answer. It won't be visible in browser **but will very well be present in your DOM and accessible to any user.** Sending the answer(hidden or not) to the client side is itself a **flaw in security.**

**You should only send the question to the client side(browser) and later verify it in you clean() method.**

If I understand you use case correctly(correct me if I'm wrong), you should do something like:

In your views.py, do something like:

```
def custom_register(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect(reverse('profile', host='profiles'))

if request.method == 'GET':   

    # Grab a random registration security Q&A
    qa_count = SecurityQuestion.objects.count() - 1
    sec_qa = SecurityQuestion.objects.all()[randint(0, qa_count)]
    #Give the text of your question to sec_qa_title. Do something like the following.
    #sec_qa_title = sec_qa.title        
    #sec_qa_title should now have the question string of the SecurityQuestion model object instance. 

    form = UserRegistrationForm(initial={'question' : sec_qa_title})

    #initialize whatever context variables you want.
    #Rest of your code.
    #return a suitable response which will display you form with the security question.


    #return render(request, 'profiles/register.html', context)

if request.method == 'POST':
    #All the data of form submitted by the user is inside request.POST
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

    # Validate the registration form
    if form.is_valid():
        #Do your stuff. Return a suitable response.

    else:
        #Do your stuff. Return a suitable response.
```

Now in your forms.py, do something like:

```
class UserRegistrationFirstForm(forms.ModelForm):

    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email_confirm = forms.EmailField()

    question = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    #removed hidden_answer field and added a question field.
    answer = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'email_confirm',
            'password',
            'password_confirm',
            #Remove the answer field.
        ]

    def clean_answer(self):
        security_question_title = self.cleaned_data.get("question")
        #get the question title.
        formatted_user_answer = self.cleaned_data.get("answer").lower()

        #now get the SecurityQuestion model.
        try:
            sec_qa = SecurityQuestion.objects.get(title = security_question_title)
            #Don't forget to import SecurityQuestion model.
        except SecurityQuestion.DoesNotExist:
            #If a user changes the question, you don't want it to fiddle with you system.
            raise forms.ValidationError("Question was changed. Wrong practice.")

        #Finally check the answer.
        if formatted_user_answer != sec_qa.answer.lower():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect answer to security question!")

        return answer
```

There are many improvements that you can later try.

For example: Sending a question and an id with it to later extract the question through that id(instead of extracting it from the whole string; slightly unreliable)

I hope you understand the flow and construct it correctly.

There may be some errors since I didn't test the code but I hope you'll fix them.

I hope this guides you in some way. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. A little bit of tweaking and it worked like a charm. I switched to sending id instead of question string. I do have one more question. For the try/except part, how exactly would a user change the question? I'm just curious, this doesn't matter so much, as the measure is just there to prevent spambots from registering account. If these rather unique questions are somehow bypassed by bots, gonna have to add recaptcha to the form.

Comment: To understand why I used try/except(which is a good practice in general), you should first know that request.POST is a simple dictionary of data sent to your server by the client(through a browser or something else). Now any client can send whatever data in this dictionary. Suspicious clients might send it through a script. Now think about it. What if inside this dictionary, a client changed the question text? It's very simple indeed. As you might be aware that Model.objects.get() throws an error if an entry doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: So if you think that request.POST looks like: {'question' : 'my_question_text' , 'other_fields' : 'other_field_strings' , ... }, a user can very well send something like: {'question' : 'manipulated_text_will_throw_an_error' , 'other_fields' : 'other_field_strings' , ... }. Now if you don't put try/catch then an error will be thrown. Hence you use try/catch. You don't want the user to send some random string to fiddle with your database.